# Movie trailer: Kidnapped little girl shooting herself with handgun

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a movie the trailer of which I've watched in 2014-2015 on YouTube.

The bad guys have kidnapped little girl. They tied her to a chair.
In a place like the warehouse.
The bad guys have talked on the phone with the girl's father.
After his father came to the warehouse and fought the bad guys.

Father came to his daughter. 
Crying little girl, took a gun and shot herself.

Little girl 8-11 years old. They spoke in English. Movie release date should be 2014 to 2016.

Comment: Unless all of this happens at the very beginning, it seems very strange that they put such a spoiler in the trailer. Are you *absolutely* sure about all of these details (that the girl shoots herself, that it's her father, that it's a trailer and not a TV promo etc.)?

Comment: I'm not so sure. I don't understand English.
I think that his low-budget film.

Comment: Finally found it.  I remember a little bit wrong.

Penance (2014)  - (I can't find this on imdb.)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2Xyl-CXNkc

Should I delete this question?

Comment: Well done on finding it. Seems the problem was that the movie never existed and this trailer was rather a [pitch for a film competition](https://vimeo.com/82366451). You don't have to delete your answer, though - if you want, you can answer it yourself with some details and approve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it.

[Penance (2014) Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2Xyl-CXNkc)

> A group of kidnappers who abduct the young daughter of a mysterious
>   family find themselves battling supernatural forces and each other
>   when the girl turns out to be the central cog in an evil plan.
>
> As the Andras family unleash the full brunt of their supernatural
>   powers to retrieve their daughter, the kidnappers must discover the
>   terrifying truth about why they need her back before her seventh
>   birthday, while surviving the night and each other…